# How to rsync just the current folder?

Tags: rsync

I want to sync some files from a remote server to my local computer. How can I make rsync to just copy the files with a certain file extension in the directory but no subdirectories?

I assumed this to be an easy task, but embarassingly I'm not getting it for nearly 2 hours. So could someone give me an example?

I did various experiments with something like the following command:

```
rsync -a --include=what? --exclude=what? -e ssh me@server.com:/test /test
```

Comment: see also:  https://superuser.com/questions/905126/rsync-copying-current-directory-with-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want one extension, in one directory, why not just use regular globbing?

```
rsync /home/you/rsync_this/*.jpg user@server:/remote/folder/
```

You can even copy multiple extensions with:

```
rsync /home/you/rsync_this/*.{jpg,png,gif} user@server:/remote/folder/
```

Comment: I was simply not aware of this... But it's acutally the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
rsync $(pwd)/*.stuff  user@server:$(pwd)
```

$(pwd) will expand to the current dir on both sides and you will save yourself some typing ;)